# How to filter out VBA with dynamic multiple dates

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty much new to vba and my problem is that I need to filter out specific dates in one table.

The logic is to filter out unwanted dates per week. 
An example is that my raw data contains dates from 10/29/2017 - 11/06/2017 when I need the dates only for 10/30/2017-11/05/2017. I tried to record a macro but I need it to be dynamic since this is running weekly.

Here's the code I've gotten so far.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table6").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "10/30/2017", 2, "10/31/2017", 2, "11/1/2017", _
        2, "11/2/2017", 2, "11/3/2017", 2, "11/4/2017", 2, "11/5/2017")
```

Hoping someone helps!
Thanks in advance

Comment: So you always filter out the 2 shoulder dates?

Comment: I haven't heard the term *shoulder* used in that context in years.

Comment: @Jeeped Come work in the corporate hotel world, then you'll hear shoulder dates/shoulder nights plenty enough ;)

Comment: @dwirony yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function which can return an array consist of the week followed by the given date. I edited the function so that you can input a date, which will generate a week after that date, or two dates, which will generate the date array between 2 given dates.

```
Private Function GenWeek(ByVal Day1 As Date, Optional ByVal Day2 As Date) As Variant
    Dim Week() As Variant
    If Day2 <> 0 Then
        ReDim Week(1 To (Day2 - Day1 + 1) * 2) As Variant
    Else
        ReDim Week(1 To 14) As Variant
    End If

    For i = 1 To UBound(Week) / 2
        Week(i * 2 - 1) = 2
        Week(i * 2) = Day1 + i - 1
    Next i

    GenWeek = Week
End Function
```

And your code can be rewritten as following.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table6").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=GenWeek(Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it *between* two 'shoulder' dates (as text).

```
Dim d1 As String, d2 As String
d1 = Format(Date - Weekday(Date, vbThursday), "\>\=mm/dd/yyyy")
d2 = Format(Date - Weekday(Date, vbThursday) + 6, "\<\=mm/dd/yyyy")
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table6")
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Operator:=xlAnd, _
                    Criteria1:=d1, Criteria2:=d2
End With
```

Comment: Double-check the results with this date format mask; it may need to be `"\>\=mm/d/yyyy"` or `"\>\=m/d/yyyy"`